# Why does my Javascript function not run/work when I call it in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I've tried numerous ways of calling the function itself. I'm rather new to PHP/Javascript, so I'm trying to learn it as I go.

I've made a function that checks if a certain checkbox is checked or not. What I want the function to do is redirect the page to another page if the checkbox IS checked, while displaying an alert box if it is unchecked.

The variables I pass through the javascript function are from my PHP code, so I was thinking my issue might be related to how the two languages interact with each other.

Here is my code. I fetch the various variables from a SQL database and store it in PHP variables. I call the function just after the commented line in the PHP code:

```js
function checkReceived(received, profEmail){
 if (received == checked){
  window.location.assign('https://someurl.php?email=' + profEmail');
 } else{
  alert("LOL HOW ABOUT NO");
 }
}
```

```css
<?php
 //This loop populates the ticket display using the records in the database
 while($recordSet->EOF == false){
  $ticketNumber = $recordSet->Fields['TicketNumber'];
  $dateSubmitted = $recordSet->Fields['DateSubmitted'];
  $department = $recordSet->Fields['Department'];
  $courseNo = $recordSet->Fields['CourseNumber'];
  $instructorName = $recordSet->Fields['InstructorName'];
  $received = ($recordSet->Fields['Received']) ? "checked" : "unchecked";
  $sendReminder = ($recordSet->Fields['SendReminder']) ? "checked" : "unchecked";
  $email = $recordSet->Fields['Email'];
  $CC = $recordSet->Fields['CC'];


  $strHTML  = "<tr><td>$dateSubmitted</td>";
  $strHTML .= "<td>$department</td>";
  $strHTML .= "<td>$courseNo</td>";
  $strHTML .= "<td style='word-break: break-all'>$instructorName</td>";
  $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' ".$received." class='receivedCheckbox' onchange='checkboxClicked(\"Received\", ".$ticketNumber.")'/> </td>";
  $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' ".$sendReminder." class='sendReminderCheckbox' onchange='checkboxClicked(\"SendReminder\", ".$ticketNumber.")' data-email='".$email."'/> </td>";
  //$strHTML .= "<td style='word-break: break-all;' align='center'> <a href='javascript:checkReceived($received, $email)'>".$email."</a></td>";
  $strHTML .= "<td><button id='emailButton' onclick='checkReceived($received, $email)'>".$email."</button></td>";
  $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <button onclick=\"window.open('https://someurl.php?ticketNumber=".$ticketNumber."')\">Print</button> </td>";
  $strHTML .= "</tr>";

  echo $strHTML;

  $recordSet->MoveNext;
 }
?>
```

As per request, here is my $strHTML:

```html
<td>Psychology</td>
<td>1000</td>
<td style='word-break: break-all'>Some Name</td>
<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' checked class='receivedCheckbox' onchange='checkboxClicked("Received", 31)'/> </td>
<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' unchecked class='sendReminderCheckbox' onchange='checkboxClicked("SendReminder", 31)' data-email='email@email.ca'/></td>
<td><button id='emailButton' onclick='checkReceived(checked, email@email.ca)'>email@email.ca</button></td>
<td align='center'> <button onclick="window.open('https://someurl.php?ticketNumber=31')">Print</button> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `if (received == checked){` what's "checked"?

Comment: it was a string, I forgot to make that change when I posted here, but I have already changed it to (received == "checked").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, don't write

```
if (received == checked){
```

but

```
if (received == "checked"){
```

you want to compare the variable `received` with the string `"checked"`.
Through PHP, the `received` variable *received* the value `"checked"` or `"unchecked"`

```
$received = ($recordSet->Fields['Received']) ? "checked" : "unchecked";
```

then it is converted to HTML with a javascript function call. The javascript function must be called with strings like

`checkReceived("string", "string")`,

so in PHP it becomes

`echo "checkReceived(\"string\", \"string\")";`

and with PHP variables

`echo "checkReceived(\"$var1\", \"$var2\")";`

in your code, it becomes:

```
$strHTML .= "<td><button id='emailButton' onclick='checkReceived(\"$received\", \"$email\")'>$email</button></td>";
```

To see if function `checkReceived()` is called, insert a `console.log()` statement and look in your browser's debugger JavaScript Console.

```
checkReceived(received, profEmail){
    console.log(received, profEmail);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I actually already made this change, but it still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Did you look at the browser's Debugger JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: Yes I did, I kept getting a "Syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token" for when I call the function. Is it a type mismatch that could be happening?

Comment: I've added $strHTML to my question, console.log() doesn't show anything when I execute the function. It just relays me the error once again.

Comment: You might need to do this `$strHTML .= "<td><button id='emailButton' onclick='checkReceived(\"$received\", \"$email\")'>".$email."</button></td>";` So that your HTML prints like `<td><button id='emailButton' onclick='checkReceived("checked", "email@email.ca")'>email@email.ca</button></td>`

Comment: @SwashataGhosh indeed, I was just editing that into ` $strHTML .= "<td><button id='emailButton' onclick='checkReceived(\"$received\", \"$email\")'>$email</button></td>";
`

Comment: This was indeed the solution, thank you both for helping me!!

Comment: Woops, I should have checked before posting my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when concatenating the html from php. You should use escape sequence when callin function (ex `onchange=\"checkboxClicked('Received', ".$ticketNumber.")\"`)

```
$strHTML  = "<tr><td>$dateSubmitted</td>";
    $strHTML .= "<td>$department</td>";
    $strHTML .= "<td>$courseNo</td>";
    $strHTML .= "<td style='word-break: break-all'>$instructorName</td>";
    $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' ".$received." class='receivedCheckbox' onchange=\"checkboxClicked('Received', ".$ticketNumber.")\"/> </td>";
    $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' ".$sendReminder." class='sendReminderCheckbox' onchange=\"checkboxClicked('SendReminder', ".$ticketNumber.")\" data-email='".$email."'/> </td>";
    //$strHTML .= "<td style='word-break: break-all;' align='center'> <a href='javascript:checkReceived($received, $email)'>".$email."</a></td>";
    $strHTML .= "<td><button id='emailButton' onclick=\"checkReceived('$received', '$email')\">".$email."</button></td>";
    $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <button onclick=\"window.open('https://someurl.php?ticketNumber=".$ticketNumber."')\">Print</button> </td>";
    $strHTML .= "</tr>";
```

and in javascript function `if(checked == "checked")` with quotes

Answer (score 1):

I am expanding my answer from the comment with better explanation.

First of all in JS, do not compare variable with `checked`, rather compare with `"checked"` (i.e, string) as @PaulH has mentioned.

So your JS should look like:

```
function checkReceived(received, profEmail){
    if (received == "checked"){
        window.location.assign('https://someurl.php?email=' + profEmail);
    } else{
        alert("LOL HOW ABOUT NO");
    }
}
```

Now for the PHP, in the line `$strHTML .= "<td><button id='emailButton' onclick='checkReceived($received, $email)'>".$email."</button></td>";` you are not wrapping the output of `$received` and `$email` variable inside a quote (`"`). It is necessary because it would print HTML which will pass strings to the JS function. So your PHP code needs to look like this:

```
<?php
    //This loop populates the ticket display using the records in the database
    while($recordSet->EOF == false){
        $ticketNumber = $recordSet->Fields['TicketNumber'];
        $dateSubmitted = $recordSet->Fields['DateSubmitted'];
        $department = $recordSet->Fields['Department'];
        $courseNo = $recordSet->Fields['CourseNumber'];
        $instructorName = $recordSet->Fields['InstructorName'];
        $received = ($recordSet->Fields['Received']) ? "checked" : "unchecked";
        $sendReminder = ($recordSet->Fields['SendReminder']) ? "checked" : "unchecked";
        $email = $recordSet->Fields['Email'];
        $CC = $recordSet->Fields['CC'];


        $strHTML  = "<tr><td>$dateSubmitted</td>";
        $strHTML .= "<td>$department</td>";
        $strHTML .= "<td>$courseNo</td>";
        $strHTML .= "<td style='word-break: break-all'>$instructorName</td>";
        $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' ".$received." class='receivedCheckbox' onchange='checkboxClicked(\"Received\", ".$ticketNumber.")'/> </td>";
        $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' ".$sendReminder." class='sendReminderCheckbox' onchange='checkboxClicked(\"SendReminder\", ".$ticketNumber.")' data-email='".$email."'/> </td>";
        //$strHTML .= "<td style='word-break: break-all;' align='center'> <a href='javascript:checkReceived($received, $email)'>".$email."</a></td>";
        $strHTML .= "<td><button id='emailButton' onclick='checkReceived(\"$received\", \"$email\")'>".$email."</button></td>";
        $strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <button onclick=\"window.open('https://someurl.php?ticketNumber=".$ticketNumber."')\">Print</button> </td>";
        $strHTML .= "</tr>";

        echo $strHTML;

        $recordSet->MoveNext;
    }
?>
```

Let me know how that turned out.